# <property object at 0x...> when trying to get a Discord name (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

New to discord.py, immediately hit a roadblock when trying to fetch a username from the user object.

EDIT: I'm also trying to find out how to utilize the User object, so I can access other useful information

Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)

user = discord.Member

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.watching, name = 'Test!'))
    print(f"""Bot is on!  Hello World :D!
Logged in as {client.user}
ID: {client.user.id}""")
    
@client.command()
async def t(ctx):
    await ctx.send(user.name)
```

Instead of printing the name as well, a name, it prints "<property object at 0x...>".

Tried using discord.User as well, no luck.

Comment: what is this: user=discord.Member?
First of all you should not use discord private classes, secondly to instantiate a member you have to do: `user=discord.Member()` and provide some arguments you don't have knowledge of. What were you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: You can easily utilize the `ctx` parameter within your `t` command, as shown below:
`await ctx.send(ctx.author)`
Here are the links to [the documentation for Context (ctx)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) and the [author attribute documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)
Example: you can access the author's name using `ctx.author.name`

Comment: @anom907zat Initially I had user within `async def t(ctx)` as `async def t(ctx, user: discord.Member)` which I had seen being used in the discord.py examples under basic_bot.py, but whenever I ran the command, my terminal says that a required argument that is missing

Comment: @Paul Thanks!  I'm aware of `ctx.author`, and it did work to find the name, so hooray!  However, I actually was very vague with my goal, I was also trying to find more on user's information so I was looking to find out how to use the User object, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, `discord.Member` is a class object, there is nothing assigned to it currently. If you want to fetch a specific user, you can use `user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)` and then use `await ctx.send(user.display_name) #or name`

You also need a `client.run("TOKEN")` at the end.

EDIT 1:
Changed to `ctx.send(user.name)`
Credits to @Raymus

Comment: Apologies!  My post was super duper vague as to what I wanted to achieve.  I was trying to figure out how to get the username of whoever sent the command, furthermore I was looking to also get the user's ID as well.  Thanks for the comment, I appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem! You can just use `await ctx.send(ctx.author.username)` to send the users name. To get the user's ID, just use `await ctx.send(ctx.author.id)`

Comment: Thank you so much, you're honestly a lifesaver!  This was exactly what I was looking for, I honestly do apologize for my poorly-worded question.

Comment: @SomeThings there's no attribute `username` that exists, at least not in discord.py. Commonly, the name of the user is obtained with `User.display_name` or `User.name`. Since the OP is doing this in a command, with `ctx`, there's no need to fetch the user. You can get the object directly with `ctx.author`.